# Suppose $A\unlhd G, A\leq B\leq G.$ Show that $B\unlhd G$ if and only if $B/A \unlhd G /A.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Suppose $A\unlhd G, A\leq B\leq G.$ Show that $B\unlhd G$ if and only if $B/A \unlhd G /A.$

I think one might be able to use the correspondence theorem. I was thinking of finding a surjective homomorphism like $\phi : G/A\to  G/B, \phi(gA) = gB,$ but $G/B$ isn't even a group unless we assume $B$ is normal.

Alternatively, I could use the direct approach and show that $g (B/A) = (B/A) g$ for all $g\in G$ if $B\unlhd G$ and conversely that $g B = Bg\,\forall g \in G$ if $B/A \unlhd G/A,$ though this alternative approach is quite messy and I think using the correspondence theorem simplifies things.

Comment: Are you assuming that $A$ is normal in $G$, or only normal in $B$? The problem statement says the latter, but then $G/A$ isn't necessarily a group. On the other hand, if $A$ is normal in $G$, then the surjective homomorphism you need in order to apply the correspondence theorem is simply $\phi : G \to G/A$, $\phi(g) = gA$.

Comment: Assuming you mean $A\triangleleft G$ and not, as you write, $A\triangleleft B$... Hint: if $g\in G$, $b\in B$, then $gbg^{-1}A = (gA)(bA)(gA)^{-1}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks for pointing out that typo. Also, can you elaborate on your hint?

Comment: That depends. Are you also going to delete this post once you get the answer you were looking for, like you did [your previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4163450/proving-products-of-groups-are-isomorphic)?

Comment: Actually, no. I think it's worthwhile to keep this question.

Comment: He says... after deleting it and then changing his mind. What exactly are you trying to hide, or why was the previous one deleted? I don't really feel like elaborating, given this history. If you want help that you will then hide so that nobody but you can see it, I'll be happy to charge you my usual consulting fee for one-on-one meetngs.